# bash: using expect to automate GPG signing

Tags: bash, expect, rpm, yum, gnupg

I am writing a bash script that automates the signing of RPM packages in a YUM repository. To accomplish this task, I use `expect`.

Here is my source code so far:

```
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn bash -c "rpm --resign ${NEW_REPO}/packages/*.rpm"
expect "Enter pass phrase:"
send "${GPG_PASS}\r"
expect eof
EOD
```

`NEW_REPO` is the path to the YUM repo, and `GPG_PASS` is the password for the GPG key.

For the most part, this works quite well and succeeds in signing packages.

**The Problem:** this code block only signs between 28-30 RPM packages even though the directory contains 42 packages. Manually signing the batch of RPM packages from the command line works perfectly, but the `expect` block in my script simply stops before it reaches all of the packages. Is this some wierd quirk of `expect`, or am I doing something completely wrong? Workarounds/suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably just timing out. Try adding:

```
set timeout 600
```

Or if you want to wait forever:

```
set timeout -1
```

As the first line of your expect script.

Comment: do you mean the first line of the `expect` block, or in my bash script prior to the `expect` block?

Comment: I'm impressed the default timeout of 10 seconds lets it get as far as it does actually but this is certainly the solution.

Comment: First line of your expect block.

Comment: Yeah this worked. The default of 10 was indeed mentioned in the man page...I just didn't think to check that at all. I guess I didn't `expect` that to be the issue......

Comment: I see what you did there. Well played. Was this entire question written so that you could drop that pun in somewhere?

Comment: Haha no, that pun wasn't my reason for writing this question. I legitimately did no understand why `expect` was stopping short. The opportunity for that pun presented itself, and I took it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using expect, you could use [gpg-agent](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html) which will allow you to GPG sign things without needing to enter a passphrase each time. You can set a long expiration time that way you can sign lots of stuff and only re-enter your passphrase periodically.

It's a lot safer than storing your GPG key password in plain text in a script like that.